# Old value in scrollbar event

Tags: events, javafx, scrollbar

I have a vertical scroll bar. When it resized triggers an event that checks if it is 100% or more to hide it but instead to get the new size value just get the old one. The visibility changes OK but not the size:

```
scrollBarL.heightProperty().addListener((ObservableValue<? extends Number> ov,
                                                        Number old_val, Number new_val) -> {    

if (scrollBarL.getVisibleAmount() >= 1 ) {              
           scrollBarL.setMaxWidth(0);    // Not change width immediately
           scrollBarL.setPrefWidth(0);   // Not change width immediately
           scrollBarL.setMinWidth(0);    // Not change width immediately             
           scrollBarL.setVisible(false); // OK. Change visibility immediately
   } else {           
           scrollBarL.setMaxWidth(19);   // Not change width immediately
           scrollBarL.setPrefWidth(19);  // Not change width immediately
           scrollBarL.setMinWidth(19);   // Not change width immediately
           scrollBarL.setVisible(true);  // OK. Change visibility immediately
        }
    });
```

Comment: Probably the change listener on the height property is triggered before the visible amount is recomputed. Why not register a listener directly with the `visibleAmount` property? (It sounds a bit like you are trying to reproduce the functionality of a scroll pane. Can you just use a scroll pane?)

Comment: Correct. With visibleAmountProperty works fine but the scrollbar remains visible/invisible until I passed over the scrollbar container with the mouse, why? @Oundroni

Comment: Works just fine for me. Create a [MCVE] and [edit] your question to include it.

Comment: The visibility is correct but no the change of size. why?